# Выборка из ассоциативного массива для вставки значений в html

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, массивы

Вот массив goodsCardsArray.

```
Array
(
    [244] => Array
        (
            [goodImgUrl] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_02.jpg
            [goodImgAlt] => Infographics
        )

    [241] => Array
        (
            [goodImgUrl] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_01-1.jpg
            [goodImgAlt] => UX/UI design
        )

    [234] => Array
        (
            [goodImgUrl] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_03.jpg
            [goodImgAlt] => Slide 2
        )

)
```

Нужно сделать в html  типа такого чтобы вывести изображения

```
<img src='goodImgUrl' alt='goodImgAlt' />
```

Как сделать такую выборку?

Comment: Вы можете использовать **for..in** оператор (в JS) для перебора ассоциативного массива. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/*
Массив вида:
(
    [244] => Array
        (
            [goodImgUrl] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_02.jpg
            [goodImgAlt] => Infographics
        )

    [241] => Array
        (
            [goodImgUrl] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_01-1.jpg
            [goodImgAlt] => UX/UI design
        )

    [234] => Array
        (
            [goodImgUrl] => http://karvan/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/thumb_03.jpg
            [goodImgAlt] => Slide 2
        )

)
На стороне PHP я форматировал массив в JSON с помощью json_encode();
*/

const goodsCardsArrayJson = '{"244":{"goodImgUrl":"http:\/\/karvan\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/06\/thumb_02.jpg","goodImgAlt":"Infographics"},"241":{"goodImgUrl":"http:\/\/karvan\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/06\/thumb_01-1.jpg","goodImgAlt":"UX\/UI design"},"234":{"goodImgUrl":"http:\/\/karvan\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/06\/thumb_03.jpg","goodImgAlt":"Slide 2"}}';

const goodsCardsArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(goodsCardsArrayJson));

const container = document.querySelector('.container');

goodsCardsArray.forEach(item => {
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = item.goodImgUrl;
    image.alt = item.goodImgAlt;
    container.appendChild(image);
});
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```